# How to make the scrollbar of a scrollviewer in XAML be non-interactive

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to create a UWP calculator app and for the display I have a slight issue. The calculator is the type that you input the text and eventually click enter and it respects orders of operation. As such, the input may get quite long so I'll need a scrollviewer around a textbox. I'm working on Windows 10 Creator's Update but the app should be backwards compatible to release version if possible.

I intend on using buttons to control cursor position, but I'd still like to have a scrollbar to indicate where you are, horizontally, in the long string. I can't figure out how to make the scrollbar there only as a visual indicator, not as a way of controlling the scrollviewer. When the mouse cursor goes near it the scrollbar expands and allows user input; this I want to avoid.

This is my display currently, very basic. How would I go about modifying that scrollviewer to my purposes?

```
<Border>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Margin="5" FontSize="24" Text="long string of testing text"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable hit testing on the `ScrollBar`:

```
<Border>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ScrollViewer.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible"
                        Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True"
                 Margin="5"
                 FontSize="24"
                 Text="long string of testing text" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Works like a charm.